# MySql survey distinct query

Tags: php, mysql, survey

Hey guys I really am struggling with a `MySql` query, I have a table named 'info' and in it I have a column called 'rating' in it I have ratings between 1-10.

Now I need to generate a percentage value of how many ratings are from 1-6 and 7-8 and 9-10 but I need them to display desperately and after that I need a second query that can subtract the percentage value of the results from 1-6 and 9-10.

The query below is as close as I could get from all my research however I don't know how to get a percentage of ratings 1-6 only and not all of them and also how to get a second query to subtract the 1-6 and 9-10 rating percentages.

```
SELECT rating, 
   COUNT(*) AS Count, 
   (COUNT(*) / _total ) * 100 AS Percentege 
FROM info, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS _total FROM info) AS myTotal 
GROUP BY rating
```

Comment: I would make a simple GROUP BY rating query and process the resulting array in PHP to get the rating percentages I need.

Comment: Ok not sure how to explain but the group by function not sure if that would work.

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select if(rating between 1 and 6, '1-6', 
          if( rating between 7 and 8, '7-8',
              '9-10' )
          ) as rating_range,
          count(1) as num
from info 
group by rating_range
```

[Working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4dc5f/7)

**Edit: Adding rounding and calculations**
This can be used as a subquery.  Given the group by you need to get the total amount seperately:

```
select Q.rating_range, 
       Q.num,
       round(Q.num * 100 / Q.total, 2) as percent
from (
    select  R.*, 
        (select count(1) from info) as total
    from (
        select if(rating between 1 and 6, '1-6', 
                  if( rating between 7 and 8, '7-8',
                      '9-10' )
                  ) as rating_range,
                  count(1) as num
        from info 
        group by rating_range ) R
    ) Q
group by Q.rating_range
```

In terms of relative values, I would probably do that in my external application if I had one.  Otherwise you could do a specific query I suppose:

```
select Q.rating_range, 
       Q.num,
       round(Q.num * 100 / Q.total, 2) as percent,      
       round( (Q.num - Q.total_nine_ten) * 100 / Q.total, 2) as diff_from_nine_ten      
from (
    select  R.*, 
        (select count(1) from info) as total,
        (select count(1) from info where rating > 8 ) as total_nine_ten
    from (
        select if(rating between 1 and 6, '1-6', 
                  if( rating between 7 and 8, '7-8',
                      '9-10' )
                  ) as rating_range,
                  count(1) as num
        from info 
        group by rating_range ) R
    ) Q 
group by Q.rating_range
```

[Fiddle for version above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4dc5f/11)

Not very elegant, but works

Comment: Yes that is nearly it I just need it to have a percentage value rounded off, one more question how would I be able to subtract the percentage value of rating 1-6 with 9-10?

Comment: Need to ask my Dreamweaver is giving an error saying the syntax is wrong from line 2 when I add the recordset, but it works fine in phpmyadmin any ideas why?

Comment: Sorry, never used dreamweaver so no idea.

Comment: It says the MySql does not support it by that version any idea what I can change in your syntax to get it to work the exact error is "mysql Error#: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') Q group by rating range' at line 2"

Answer (score 1):

I don't like that idea itself, but if you need you can:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd1c5/1

```
SELECT rating, 
   COUNT(*) AS Count, 
   (COUNT(*) /  COALESCE ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS _total FROM info),1) ) * 100 AS Percentege 
FROM info
GROUP BY rating
```

or if we are sure that table is not empty:

```
SELECT rating, 
   COUNT(*) AS Count, 
   (COUNT(*) /  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM info) ) * 100 AS Percentege 
FROM info
GROUP BY rating
```

**UPDATE** Even more weird but requested result:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b6bf/4

```
SELECT  
  IF(rating>=0 AND rating<=6, '1-6',
            IF(rating<=8,'7-8',
               IF(rating<=10,'9-10','UNKNOWN')
            )
          ) as pseudo_rating,
   COUNT(*) AS Count, 
   (COUNT(*) /  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM info) ) * 100 AS Percentege 
FROM info
GROUP BY pseudo_rating
```

**UPDATE** [ROUND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b6bf/6

```
SELECT  
  IF(rating>=0 AND rating<=6, '1-6',
            IF(rating<=8,'7-8',
               IF(rating<=10,'9-10','UNKNOWN')
            )
          ) as pseudo_rating,
   COUNT(*) AS Count, 
   ROUND((COUNT(*) /  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM info) ) * 100, 2) AS Percentege 
FROM info
GROUP BY pseudo_rating
```

Comment: The Table would look like below:

--------------------
| Rating            |
|-------------------|                   |
| 10                |
| 8                 |
| 10                |
| 8                 |
| 9                 |
| 2                 |
| 2                 |
| 4                 |
| 4                 |
| 8                 |
--------------------

Desired result would be ratings 9-10 = 30%

Comment: @DanielSmit did you try my query? did you visit my sqlfiddle?

Comment: The one you submitted gives all the results the same as mine, however I need the results to be separate  and grouped with ratings 1-6 and 7-8 and 9-10...

Comment: Thanks man one last question though, how can I round the percentage results and subtract the percentage result 1-6 with 9-10... Thanks in advance your a boss man I really was struggling...

Comment: @DanielSmit check `round()` function. answer updated